# What public statements has Theresa May made regarding fox hunting?

Tags: united-kingdom, conservative-party, theresa-may

The UK fox hunting ban has been enforced since February 2005. In Theresa May's 2017 manifesto, she promised a free vote on the fox hunting ban.

What public statements did Theresa May make to support bringing this vote?

Comment: I'm voting to close, on the grounds that mind reading Mrs. May will end up being opinion. The only real evidence I know of are opinion polls, which still suggest that more people support the ban than oppose it, in both urban and rural areas: https://yougov.co.uk/news/2015/01/09/british-people-still-support-fox-hunting-ban/ https://www.ipsos.com/ipsos-mori/en-uk/attitudes-hunting-2016?language_content_entity=en-uk

Comment: @origimbo: I'd request that you hold your VTC. It may be that she has given a reason for the inclusion herself, for example.

Comment: If your goal is to find her public announcements, rather than her actual intention, I suggest you reword the question.

Comment: @RupertMorrish: your edit changed the question quite a bit.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Yes. It was presented to me as a question that could be reopened if it were edited, so I did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Theresa May voted against the ban on fox hunting in 2005 and on previous occasions. She has declared that she is personally in favour of fox hunting

> “This is a situation on which individuals will have one view or the other, either pro or against. As it happens, personally I have always been in favour of fox hunting and we maintain our commitment, we have had a commitment previously as a Conservative party, to allow a free vote.”

https://www.ft.com/content/0b89d3fa-34cf-11e7-99bd-13beb0903fa3

The evidence is that this is a genuine belief of May, and one that does have support among the Tory base.